# Can I update my old servers to new openssh>

Tags: ssh, openssh

My current machine is 16.04 and this is my current ssh version:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
```

but I have a bunch of older servers that I cannot use apt-get to update them,

So I have a few questions. I do have the current version of openssh in a tarball.

Can I update older machines from my current machine? If so how?

The `openssh-7.5.tar.gz` is I guess the BSD version and says `Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop.` when I try to use it on another Ubuntu server. Is there a way I could use this?

Does anyone have a workaround for updating these old systems?

They need to be version 7 or higher.

Comment: *"The openssh-7.5.tar.gz is I guess the BSD version and says Makefile:3: *** missing separator.  Stop. when I try to use it on another Ubuntu server."* whoaa - you're leaving out quite a few steps there, it's hard to offer any help without the specifics. For a general answer, see [How can I install software or packages without Internet (offline)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline)

Comment: any reason for not downloading the DEB installer, the dependencies and use dpkg to install them?

Comment: The portable version [Openssh](https://www.openssh.com/portable.html) You may have compatibility issues with the zlib package on older systems and need to exclude zlib compression during configure.